# jquery menu-aim hide the popover-content

Tags: jquery

for the jquery menu-aim ( https://github.com/kamens/jQuery-menu-aim )

I try to auto hide the popover content when user move away the cursor from the popover or the menu so I have

```
$(document).hover(function() {
  $(".popover").css("display", "none");
  $("a.maintainHover").removeClass("maintainHover");
});
```

But this doesn't hide the popover right away.

Can you suggest how do I solve this ?

Thanks in advance